# Homework questions in ergodic theory

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be iid.  If $f: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable wrt the product structure it's $L^1$ under the distribution measure induced by the $X_i$ then why is it true that $1/n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(X_k, X_{k+1}, ... )$ converges a.s. to $Ef(X_1, ...)$?  Please show this by only using SLLN, as opposed to pointwise ergodic theorem. (Which my class knows, but it's a special request from the prof)

Progress: I can see it for at first indicators of finite dimensional sets, then infinite dimensional, hence simple functions, hence by using a uniform limit and a 3$\epsilon$ argument then for all bounded $f$ of this form.  Using a different approximation scheme I can also get it if $f$ is not necessarily bounded, but is itself dependent on only finitely many of the RVs.  Trouble is what if f is absolutely general in $L^1$.  Then I think I want to use Egorov's theorem and Borel Cantelli, but I struggle to put all the pieces together.  For this problem, I am lacking creativity, not knowledge.  So feel free to use anything you want from a first graduate course in probability.

Source: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275c.1.13s/PDFs/HW1.pdf